# httpURLConnection to php server gives different response (url works on web browser)

Tags: php, android, json, mysqli, httpurlconnection

The code requests HTTP connection to server that runs with php (phpMyAdmin).
It gives response with JSONObject.

It worked when I was testing in Asia, however it gives different response in the United States.

With given url:

```
target = "http://example.com/request.php?value=DDPS"
```

This works on web browser but in Android device it gives:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/cupid.js"></script><script>
.....path=/";location.href="http://example.com/request.php?value=DDPS
&ckattempt=1";</script></body></html>
```

This fails to create JSONObject which is obvious.

What would be possible problem on this behavior?

I have set permission to server that allows access from all continents.

Here is my httpURLconnection code:

```
    try{
            URL url = new URL(target);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream inputstream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
            String temp;
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(temp).append("\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputstream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        }catch (Exception e)            {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

EDIT:

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
```

gives same behavior.

Here is my php code for getting data from database and send response in JSON format.
On which point should I implement file_get_contents?

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "exampleID", "examplePW", "exampleID");

$value = $_GET["title"];

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE title = '$value'");

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($response, array("item1"=>$row[1], "item2"=>$row[2], "item3"=>$row[3], "item4"=>$row[4]));
}

echo json_encode(array("response"=>$response), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: probably issue with server redirects. Android gets the first response.

you could verify it with using a php scropt and `file_get_contents` method

Comment: should not Content-Type header be `application/json` ?, i don't see any redirects? how is this related ?

Comment: There is no redirect in php code. 
You can create JSON with Content-Type: text/html unless they are in correct JSON format. 

Above code perfectly works. My issue was on hosting server side.
It blocked every IP address accessing from foreign countries.

Answer (score 0):

probably issue with server redirects. Android gets the first response. you could verify it with using a php scropt and file_get_contents method

You can also try

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. I tried it but it does not follow the link. Could you check my edited questions?

Comment: what redirects? i don't see any redirects in php code ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

There was no issue in android codes.
The issue was from the server I was connecting to.

It blocked some unknown IP addresses, so I needed to give permission to server to accept certain IP access.